# How to fill nested dict when you only have a list of key, value for the final layers?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dict of the folling form:

```
dict1 = {layer1: {layer2: {layer3: {a:None, b:None, c:None}}, {d:None, e:None}}}
```

And a flat dict with only the values in the final layer:

```
dict2 = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5}
```

My expected output after filling the values in the first dict would be:

```
dict_out = {layer1: {layer2: {layer3: {a:1, b:2, c:3}}, {d:4, e:5}}}
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: Write a recursive function that loops over `dict1`. If the value is another dictionary, recurse. Otherwise look up the key in `dict2` and set the value.

Comment: What are the question marks "`?`" in your example? Can it be assumed they are `None`? Also don't use `dict` as a variable name. You are shadowing the built-in `dict` name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question correctly. You can use recursion to replace the values of keys in-place:

```py
dct = {
    "layer1": {
        "layer2": {"layer3": {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0}},
        "layer4": {"d": 0, "e": 0},
    }
}

dct2 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}


def replace(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k in d & dct2.keys():
            d[k] = dct2[k]

        for k in d - dct2.keys():
            replace(d[k])

    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for i in d:
            replace(i)


replace(dct)
print(dct)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "layer1": {
        "layer2": {"layer3": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}},
        "layer4": {"d": 4, "e": 5},
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using recursion, you really only need one written loop. I find this easier to decipher. It also doesn't alter the original dict inplace:

```
data = {"layer1": {"layer2": {"layer3": {"a": None, "b": None, "c": None}, "layer4": {"d": None, "e": None}}}}
values = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}

def fill_data(data):
    out = {}

    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            out[key] = fill_data(value)
        else:
            out[key] = values.get(key, value)

    return out

print(fill_data(data))
```

---

```
{'layer1': {'layer2': {'layer3': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 'layer4': {'d': 4, 'e': 5}}}}
```